# How to run Selenium Server on Travis CI when testing a Node.js project with Nightwatch

Tags: java, node.js, selenium, travis-ci, nightwatch.js

I have a [node.js project](https://github.com/nfriedly/user-agent.io) that I am trying to use Nightwatch to test. Nightwatch uses  selenium-server under-the-hood.

My tests work correctly locally, but on Travis it immediately chokes with this [error](https://travis-ci.org/nfriedly/user-agent.io/builds/229335750#L1137):

> There was an error while starting the Selenium server:
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/grid/selenium/GridLauncherV3 : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

I *think* that means that it wants Java 8 or newer, but I'm not sure how to set that up on Travis. I tried [setting `jdk: oracle8jdk` in my travis.yml](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#JVM-(Clojure%2C-Groovy%2C-Java%2C-Scala)-VM-images), but that didn't seem to make a difference. (Maybe that only works on for Java tests?)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Trusty Environment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/trusty-ci-environment) [has](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/trusty-ci-environment#JVM) a tool called [jdk_switcher](https://github.com/michaelklishin/jdk_switcher) installed. That tool can be used to set up the correct version of Java for running selenium. Here's the important parts of [my travis.yml](https://github.com/nfriedly/user-agent.io/blob/master/.travis.yml):

```
dist: trusty
sudo: false
#...
before_script:
    #...
    - jdk_switcher use oraclejdk8
```